# Passing a void pointer to a pointer into a function

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose myStruct has a field defined as
`char *name;`
I want to pass a pointer to this field to a function that allocates memory and builds the name.

What I want to do is basically this

```
void myFunctionChar(char **ptr)
{
    *ptr = alloc(...);
}

myFunction(&myStruct->name);
```

which is fine. But the function doesn't need to know about the datatype so why not this..

```
void myFunction(void **ptr)
{
}

myFunction(&myStruct->name); // raises an error - incompatible pointers!
```

Ok but why is there an error?
I can assign every pointer to a `void*` and the function declaration seems to be ok so let's try this

```
void myFunction(void **ptr)
{
}

void **ptr = &myStruct->name;
myFunction(ptr);
```

It works!

How should I explain the second case?

Comment: the function you made expects (void**). so you just need to cast the pointer when sending it. myFunction((void**)&myStruct->name); which is pretty  much what you did in your second example

Comment: The given link answers a little of my question. I didn't find this answer before. So it looks like I am fine when I keep using the 3rd version I gave, right?

Comment: Your third snippet says "*`// Here is the error`*". Is this true?

Comment: @alk no of course this line was ok, it was a stupid copy&paste error! I edited that, thank you!

Comment: The 3rd version looks wrong... you would modify the local `ptr` without necessarily modifying the `myStruct->name`. I have some weird ideas about storing `Foo**` in `void*`, but it's probably a good way to shoot yourself in the foot some day.

Comment: @grek40 yes you are right! That wasn't correct. Unfortunately I had to write this from mind, actual code was gone at this time because I tried to do something completely different. The basic idea was to give the function a pointer to the final pointer to the string so the function can allocate memory for the string into the pointer to the string.